# Kendo UI - Append remote jsonp to template

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm new to Kendo and have hit an issue. I'm trying to some remote json in my kendo app then add it to a template/listview. I can see the response in chrome dev tools network tab and when I console.log(this.view()); in my datasource change method I get some sort of kendo code in my console which contains my results

[image: See ScreenShot]

But I cant seem to add the results to my template? Heres my code, hopefully you will be able to point me in the right direction as I'm loving Kendo but need to solve this to move forward... or its back to jquery mobile. Thanks in advance.

```
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">

<!-- Home page -->
<div data-role="view" data-layout="default" id="home">
    <p>Home</p>
</div>

<div data-role="view" data-layout="default" id="search">
    <div class="form">
        <button id="getProperties" name="getProperties" value="Get Properties" data-role="button">Get Properies</button>
    </div>
    <ul id="resultListView"/>
</div>

<!-- Settings -->
<div data-role="view" data-layout="default" id="settings">
    <p>Some settings</p>
</div>

<!-- Layout -->
<section data-role="layout" data-id="default">
    <header data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">My app</div>
    </header>
    <!--View content will render here-->
    <footer data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="tabstrip">
            <a data-icon="home" href="#home">Home</a>
            <a data-icon="search" href="#search">Search</a>
            <a data-icon="organize" href="#calculator">Calculator</a>
            <a data-icon="settings" href="#settings">Settings</a>       
        </div> 
    </footer>
</section>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<!-- Template for Property results, need to change below fields -->
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="propertiesListViewTemplate">
    <h4>${property_type}</h4>
    <p>${street_name}</p>
</script>

<script>
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, 
{
    transition:'slide'
});

function onBodyLoad() {
    getProperties(onResult);
}

function getProperties(callback) {

    var template = kendo.template($("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html());

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: 'http://www.someurl.me/getproperties.php?postcode=hx59ay',
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },

        schema: {
            data: "listing"
        },


        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Error " + e);
        },
        change: function() {
            $("#propertyResultListView").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
            console.log(this.view());
        }
    });
    dataSource.read();
    $("#propertyResultListView").kendoMobileListView({dataSource:dataSource,template: $("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html()});

}

function onResult(resultData) {
    console.log("Results " + listing); // This isnt getting logged in console...
    $("#propertyResultListView").kendoMobileListView({dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data:resultData}),
        template: $("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html()});
}

</script>
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how the retrieved JSON looks like? As far as I can see it should be a JSON object with an element called listing. Is that correct? How does listing look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You don't have an element with id="propertyResultListView" yet you use it to create a list view.
- If you are going to use the data source with a Kendo widget you don't need to do anything else but to specify it. For example handling manually the change event and rendering a template is not needed - the mobile list view will do it automatically.

You can find more info in the [list view documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/listview#binding-to-data). Also here are a few demos which may help: http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/databinding.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I've corrected the id that was missing (thats what you get from copying ad pasting from an example!) and I now have a list view. I've also removed the change event. When you mention rendering a template, which part of the code do you mean?

Comment: I meant the change event of the datasource. The listview will render its template (set via data-template) automatically.